# Angular2 Component How to Import Directive Component?

Tags: angular, angular2-components

I just upgraded to angular2 final release and there were alot of breaking changes from rc4.  One of which is there is no longer a Directives collection on the component... I uesd to do something like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'resource-tab',
    templateUrl: './app/applicationMgmt/resource/resource-tab.html',
    directives: [
        NgSwitch,
        NgSwitchCase,
        NgSwitchDefault,
        OtherResourceEditorComponent,
        MvcResourceEditorComponent,
        WcfResourceEditorComponent,
        WebResourceEditorComponent,
        WebApiResourceEditorComponent,
        ConfigResourceEditorComponent
    ]    
})
```

to reference other components that are used as directives on the view template... How does one do this now?

Comment: put this all directive, component, pipe inside `NgModule`'s `declarations` array

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way to do it would be to create a `ResourceEditorModule` like this:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations:[
            OtherResourceEditorComponent,
            MvcResourceEditorComponent,
            WcfResourceEditorComponent,
            WebResourceEditorComponent,
            WebApiResourceEditorComponent,
            ConfigResourceEditorComponent
    ],
    exports:[
            OtherResourceEditorComponent,
            MvcResourceEditorComponent,
            WcfResourceEditorComponent,
            WebResourceEditorComponent,
            WebApiResourceEditorComponent,
            ConfigResourceEditorComponent
    ]
})
export class ResourceEditorModule{}
```

and add `ResourceEditorModule` as import in your `AppModule`:

```
@NgModule({
    imports:[
        ...
        ...
        ResourceEditorModule
    ],
    ...
    ...
    ...
})
export class AppModule{}
```

The idea bedhind modules is to split your components, directives, pipes and services in groups that belongs to the same "package", like everything you need to use http for `HttpModule`, everything you need to use forms for `FormsModule`

Answer (score 5):

You should specify Components, directives and Pipes under declarations property of the NgModule. So basically the easiest way for me upgrading my angular 2 project to 2.0.0. version was defining one module for the app (app.module.ts) put all there and then start breaking it smaller modules.
Good reference for this can be found [here](https://johnpapa.net/introducing-angular-modules-feature-modules-2/)

Answer (score 4):

In Angular2.0.0 **in-built directives** are accessible/available with **BrowserModule**,. You just need to import it as shown below and you'll be able to ***most of in-built*** directives.

For customDirective, you need to declared them with  ***declarations metadata*** as shown,

```
    import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

   /*---------import all custom directives-----------*/

   import { OtherResourceEditorComponent} from 'valid path';
   import { MvcResourceEditorComponent } from 'valid path';
   ...
   ...   

    @NgModule({
      imports:      [ BrowserModule],
      declarations: [ AppComponent,OtherResourceEditorComponent,MvcResourceEditorComponent,... ],
      bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated you need to move your directives and providers to a module for your app. The [RC4 to RC5 migration guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/rc4-to-rc5.html) explains how to do this, and some other potential problems.